# Oracle possible Error in Select with FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: oracle, select, full-outer-join

I have to modify a **select of oracle** that someone do... i need to understand... I think that is a bad select but i'm no sure:

*FROM user01.myTable FULL OUTER JOIN user01.myTable* **myTable_alias2**

```
SELECT      
            myTable.field1 AS field1,
            myTable.date_hour AS date_hour,
            myTable.HOUR,
            DECODE (
                    myTable.aux1, 'CAT', 'CAT3', myTable.aux1
                    ) AS aux1,
            myTable.sum_count,
            myTable_alias2.sum_count AS sum_countx,
            myTable.aux2,
            myTable_alias2.aux2 AS aux2x
   FROM user01.myTable FULL OUTER JOIN user01.myTable myTable_alias2
            ON (myTable.field1 = myTable_alias2.field1
                  AND myTable.HOUR = myTable_alias2.HOUR
                  AND myTable.aux1 = myTable_alias2.aux1
                  AND TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (myTable.date_hour, 'YYYYMMDD') - 7,'YYYYMMDD') = myTable_alias2.date_hour
             )
```

There is in my system a **user01.myTable**, but in my system there isn't a **myTable_alias2**.
and if i replace all  myTable_alias2 with  myTable_aliasXXX the select work correctly!

i don't understand, i think that  myTable_alias2 is like a copy of user01.myTable, but if is right i can write all like this:

```
SELECT         
            myTable.field1 AS field1,
            myTable.date_hour AS date_hour,
            myTable.HOUR,
            DECODE (myTable.aux1, 'CAT01L0', 'CAT01L03', myTable.aux1) AS aux1,
            myTable.sum_count,
        myTable.aux2
FROM user01.myTable
```

in what i'm wrong? what i don't understand? is a particulary **full outer join** or is a simple error? 
ThankYou very much for your Time!

Answer (score 1):

> i think that myTable_alias2 is like a copy of user01.myTable

That is correct. The table is not actually copied but the query works as if you had 2 copies of the table and the second copy gets another name (alias), so it is distinguished from the first.

> but then, i can write all like this: ...

No, your rewriting is not equivalent to the first (FULL JOIN) version. The Join is not done entirely on the same columns.

This part:

```
   TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (myTable.date_hour, 'YYYYMMDD') - 7,'YYYYMMDD') 
   = myTable_alias2.date_hour
```

means that rows from the first copy of the table will be matched to **different** rows from the second copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not unique to full outer joins.  Any time you are joining tables, it's a good idea to alias the table names and to use those aliases to qualify the columns names.  If you are doing a self-join where you are joining a table to itself, it is necessary to alias at least one of the two instances of the table.

If I have the standard `SCOTT` tables `EMP` and `DEPT`, for example, I can write the query without aliases

```
SELECT emp.ename,
       dept.dname
  FROM emp 
       JOIN dept ON (emp.deptno = dept.deptno)
```

or I write the query with aliases

```
SELECT e.ename,
       d.dname
  FROM emp e
       JOIN dept d ON (e.deptno = d.deptno)
```

In the latter case, `E` and `D` are not objects in the database.  They are simply shorthand for the tables they alias, `EMP` and `DEPT`, that are available within the scope of the query.

If I want to join a table to itself-- say, I want a report of employees and their managers, I can write a self join

```
SELECT employee.ename,
       manager.ename
  FROM emp employee
       JOIN emp manager ON (employee.mgr = manager.empno)
```

In this case, I'm joining the `EMP` table to itself and the aliases help identify what set of data is represented by each instance of the `EMP` table.  One instance is providing the information about the employee and one instance is providing the information about the maanger.